# Transfer files over WIFI hotspot without internet connection?

Tags: networking

Can i transfer lets say movie from pc to Android, if both are connected to my wofo hotspot from android? If connection can be established between 2 PC-s, why not ohone/pc. Is there a term related to this and is there an app for android?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a local network share just as you would between two computers.

If you set up a network share on the PC, you can use an app like ES File Explorer on Android. You can browse the network share and copy files to and from the PC.

Answer (score 0):

The app that I use for this is called WiFi File Transfer.  Seems to work better from phone to pc rather then the other way around as you can't write to an external sd card but you can transfer it to your phone then move it to the external sd with a file manager program.

** I am in no way affiliated with WiFi File Transfer.  My answer is based solely on my needing to transfer a file and not having access to a USB cable. **

Comment: can u give me the link since there are many similary called.

Comment: first result googling "WiFi File Transfer": https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smarterdroid.wififiletransfer